# Creating an user input connected to my function

Tags: python, function, user-input

I would like to create a user input for a function of mine. So this function of mine is a boolean function. It is used to test whether a word is a palindrome or not by giving an output True or False.

I want to create a separate function (user input) where a person can type in the phrase that they want to find out if its a palindrome or not and it should print out the words "The phrase you entered, XXXXXX is a palindrome" when output is true and when output is false it should go "The phrase you entered, XXXXXX is not a palindrome".

My code as below:

```
def palindrome(phrase):
    len_phrase = len(phrase)//2
    print("len_phrase",len_phrase)
    for i in range(len_phrase):
        print(phrase[i],phrase[-i-1])
        if phrase[i] != phrase[-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Assuming you just want text input via the command line, you should look into the `input` function. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Comment: No I want a person to be able to enter a phrase themselves and once they do it should start printing out  "The phrase you entered, XXXXXX is a palindrome" when output is true and when output is false it should go "The phrase you entered, XXXXXX is not a palindrome". I just cant seem to link it to my function

Comment: You get user input with the "input" function, pass that to your palindrome function and test the return.

Comment: Jeff gave a nice answer. I would add a few things about the design. 1) remove print statements from your function. They are redundant in that logic. A clean function should do one thing. 2) I think that if you call the function `is_palindrome`, that would be more readable and explicit (see The Zen of Python, `import this`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `input` to request a string from the user; something like this :

```
def palindrome(phrase):
    [...]
    
user_input = input("Enter some text:")
  
if palindrome(user_input):
    print(f'{user_input} is a palindrome')
else:
    print(f'{user_input} is not a palindrome')
```